# Unit Testing Angular Attribute Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am having some problems testing an AngularJS (1.5) Attribute restricted Directive. See the below example directive and following unit test, of which produces a broken unit test.

**Directive**

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  function SomethingCtrl($filter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        var exampleFilter = $filter('exampleFilter');
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          ngModelController.$setViewValue(value);
          ngModelController.$render();
          return value;
        });
      }
    };
  }

  SomethingCtrl.$inject = ['$filter'];

  angular.module('something.formatter', [
    'filters'
  ]).directive('somethingFormatter', SomethingCtrl);
}(window.angular));
```

**Directive Unit Test**

```
fdescribe('something.formatter spec', function () {
  'use strict';
  var scope,
      element,
      testValue,
      compile,
      ngModelCtrl;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('something.formatter');

    compile = function () {
      inject([
        '$compile',
        '$rootScope',
        function ($compile, $rootScope) {
          scope = $rootScope.$new();
          scope.testValue = testValue;
          element = angular.element('<input something-formatter ng-model="testValue"');
          $compile(element)(scope);
          ngModelCtrl = element.controller('ngModel');
          scope.$digest();
        }
      ]);
    };
  });
  describe('initialization', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      testValue = 'Yay!';
      compile();
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('Nay?');
    });
    it('should be defined', function () {
      expect(scope.testValue).toEqual('Nay?');
    });
  });
});
```

I tried following these instructions: http://jsfiddle.net/mazan_robert/hdsjbm9n/

To be able to call methods on the ngModelController, like; $setViewValue.

Yet, Jasmine continues to scream at me and tells me that $setViewValue is not a constructor, as well as doesn't even hit console.logs inside the actual directive.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue')
```

Thoughts?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you close the input tag:

```
element = angular.element('<input something-formatter ng-model="testValue" />');
```

Comment: Still didn't work =/. ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue')```. But, that did log out the element though, so thanks for that tip! :)